# How to count the number of non blank lines in php

Tags: php

I have been using this code to count blank lines in a text file

```
$filePath = ".somefile.txt";
$num = count(file($filePath));
```

which works fine but includes blank lines in the count, can I use an option such as SKIP BLANK LINES
To count only lines that contain text?

I tried the above code but the result gives the total number of lines but includes blank lines

Comment: If you check [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), there is a flag called `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`. Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: This seems to give what I want  $file3 = ".data.txt";
$all_lines = file($file3);
$number_of_lines= count($all_lines);
echo "data lines = ", $number_of_lines;

Comment: What you just posted in the comment is identical to what you posted in your question though. You just added an extra variable to store the results from `file()` instead of using it directly. The result would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use flag `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`.

**Example**:

File `test.txt`:

```
HELLO
HELLO1

HELLO2
HELLO3
```

Code:

```
$file  = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines = count($file);
echo $lines; // 4
```

Comment: FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES must be used together with FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES so that no empty lines appear in the result array as your code shows.